# Creating a PDF from Word with navigation pane in PDF

Tags: pdf, ms-word

I have **MS Word 2013** and **MS Print to PDF** for creating PDF documents. I use heading styles for creating headings in my document and I can see them in Word's navigation pane. I'd like to have these headings in PDF navigation pane as well. How can I achieve this? Now when I print my document into PDF, I loose these headings from navigation pane in PDF doc!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no need for third party tools, just use the Save As dialog. Choose PDF as the 'Save as type' and click the large 'Options' button at the bottom of the dialog. In the Options dialog check 'Create bookmarks using' and ensure that 'Headings' is selected. Click OK

Word will even remember your choices and set them as the default for when you do it again.

[image: Save As PDF Options dialog]

Comment: I don't know why but when I want to create a PDF document I'm used to Print into PDF, not to Save As PDF. Thanks for this answer, this resolves my issue.

Comment: Simple and Precise. Thanks, Timothy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use MS Print to PDF; the print stream doesn't have enough information in it to create these navigational aides. Adobe Acrobat DC, as well as several other PDF creation products (Foxit, Nitro, Nuance) use macros that will interpret the styles and the navigation tree in Word to create bookmarks and set the initial view of the PDF to launch with the bookmarks open.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from that this is not so much a question for Stack Overflow, rather for its "Superuser" sibling, here is another solution for you:

In MS Word, switch your view to "Outline view". This let's you then select the level of headlines to be displayed (Level 1, Level 2, Level 3...) - provided of course you use such structured headlines (only a minority of Word users do).

Say, you want only top-level headlines displayed, then set Outline View to "Level 1".
Then simply print that page to Pdf, and there you are: the pdf shows only your headlines.

If you want to show headlines down to the third level, simply choose Level 3 to be displayed.

Here is a screenshot from Word 2010 in Outline view with only top levle headlines displayed:

[image]

Note that the Pdf will not have the +-marks in front of the paragraphs. They are control buttons that do not print.

Comment: Sorry, but you did not understand my question. I'm talking about PDF navigation pane with headings.